node-expose-sspi alternative for linux
Do we have anything like node-expose-sspi in nodejs for linux system, I need to use sso for my nodejs app in linux,please help to integrate in my app.
I tried with node-sspi but it also tell that node-sspi is for windows, need any module for linux.
